# not able to properly open c# files in unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

im trying to get into unity but i seem to have a problem.
every time i try to open a script from unity it launches the script into VS but instead of letting me run the script it just says "Attach" and its not giving me any unity code in the auto complete section while im writing it also says its a Miscellanous file at the top left of the screen where it should say its a c# project and i cant seem to get it to work, i would love some help.
i have tried to attach the project to unity yet that dosent work in addition to that the project bar where i would usually see my project and scripts in the right side of the screen dosent show up, its like im in some sort of limited read-only mode of the script.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install unity tools in vs? You shouldn’t be running it really in vs its more of an editor than a whole ide.

Answer (score 0):

i found the awnser i just needed to go into Edit -> Perference -> external tools -> and then select visual studio in external script editor

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).